# The Elasticsearch interpreter in Zeppelin does not respond to requests

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-zeppelin

I have a running Elasticsearch node in a machine. It is healthy, works fine. I can run any requests on the browser without issues. I have a zeppelin notebook where I set up the elastic interpreter. The following is how the interpreter looks like.

```
elasticsearch.basicauth.password    

elasticsearch.basicauth.username    

elasticsearch.client.type   transport

elasticsearch.cluster.name  elasticsearch

elasticsearch.host  127.0.0.1

elasticsearch.port  9300

elasticsearch.result.size   10

zeppelin.interpreter.localRepo  /path/to/repo
```

After I open a notebook, I write:

```
%elasticsearch

GET /
```

And the result is this

```
Bad URL (it should be /index/type/id)
```

Or

```
%elasticsearch

GET /

Error : None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{ip}{ip:port}]
```

Even though

```
GET host:port/
```

works just fine in a browser.

What have I done wrong?

Edit:

In addition, I am using Zeppelin 0.7.1 and Elastic 5.4

Comment: What version of Zeppelin and elasticsearch you using?

Comment: I am using Zeppelin 0.7.1 and Elastic 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elasticSearch **interpreter** in Zeppelin works differently compared to the browser URL query.

You can think elasticsearch interpreter as a DSL converter which uses its own language. For example, to send `GET` query for a document, you need to specify index, type and id.

[image]

Here is the documentation for the elasticsearch interpreter in Zeppelin 0.7.1

- http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/interpreter/elasticsearch.html#using-the-elasticsearch-interpreter

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to the configuration of elasticsearch interpreter (under the top right menu) and change the value of the paramter

elasticsearch.client.type to http

Also check if the cluster name is correct.

Then you can find here samples of how to create the requests: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/interpreter/elasticsearch.html